# Value of subject line changes while inserting in MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

Actual String:

```
$sub"=?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?= Styles to =?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?="
UTF value is decoded using:
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$subjectvalue=mb_decode_mimeheader($sub);
```

when I echoed `$subjectvalue` desired value displayed on my browser ,desired value is:

```
♣ Styles to  ♣
```

Issue:
when I tried to insert value of `$subjectvalue`, value inserted looks like

```
Ã¢Â™Â£ Styles to Ã¢Â™Â£
```

why value inserted is not as echoed on browser.
How to manage and insert value of subject line ,if it is encoded.

Comment: Does this *actually* involve MySQL? I don't see the usage of such shown anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect to your MYSQL database try running just after connecting

```
SET names 'utf8'
```

I've prepared the whole test:

1) I've created database named **testencoding**

2) I've created sample table:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


ALTER TABLE `sample`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `sample`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

You can import it into database using phpmyadmin

3)

I've created test PHP script:

```
<?php
$sub = "=?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?= Styles to =?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?=";

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$subjectvalue=mb_decode_mimeheader($sub);
$subjectvalue2 = '会意字 / 會 huìyìzì ';
echo $subjectvalue."<br />";
echo $subjectvalue2."<br />";


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testencoding");
mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO sample(`value`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$subjectvalue)."')");
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO sample(`value`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$subjectvalue2)."')");


$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM sample");
echo "<br /><br />Data from database<br /><br />";
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $data['id'].' '.$data['value']."<br />";
}
```

4) Results are:

In phpmyadmin:

[image: Result from phpmyadmin]

In PHP script:

[image: Result from php]

So to sum up, everything works as expected. Data are inserted as they should be, data in phpmyadmin and those read from database via php are the same as they were inserted

Comment: i am trying what you suggested but still same result. mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

Comment: Do you insert $sub or $subjectvalue into database? Try the other one if current is not working. To be honest I've never user strings with beginning "=?UTF-8?

Comment: value inserted looks  ? Styles to ? now

Comment: Maybe you should try simple $sub = '&clubs; Styles to &clubs;'; and you won't need using mb_decode_mimeheader and have no problem with inserting it in database

Comment: SET names 'utf8' not working . Please suggest what can done solve this

Comment: Have you tried simple change it $clubs; entity as I wrote in comment above?

Comment: sir subject value will be dynamic now i am encountered with club shape but later their might be heart shape or any other, than how i will manage.

Comment: Ok, but why your string is so strange it begins with ?UTF-8? why it's not ordinary string and why don't you put this string simple into database? Why do you mb_decode_mimeheader? Please explain and put in your question exact code you use for inserting into database

Comment: 1.String is UTF8 encoded ,we can not control this as client uses such encoding .2. I am just trying to decode it with mb_decode_mimeheader

Comment: Ok, add to question code where you insert this variable in database and insert also this table structure. I hope that table and fields have utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: I've added the whole working test script with results to my answer. Just take a look. Everything is working fine